# Export option gives strange errors in 4.3.2deb0.1 version for Ubuntu

Tags: phpmyadmin, export

When I try to use database export option I get this error:

```
Warning in ./libraries/plugins/export/ExportPdf.class.php#16
file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/php/tcpdf/tcpdf.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/)
```

Backtrace

```
./libraries/plugins/export/ExportPdf.class.php#16: file_exists(string '/usr/share/php/tcpdf/tcpdf.php')
./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#76: include_once(./libraries/plugins/export/ExportPdf.class.php)
./libraries/display_export.inc.php#31: PMA_getPlugins(
string 'export',
string 'libraries/plugins/export/',
array,
)
./server_export.php#27: require_once(./libraries/display_export.inc.php)
```

Is this phpMyAdmin bug? What do I have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and I fixed it by editing `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/vendor_config.php`

Find this like

```
     * Path to tcpdf.php file. Useful when you want to use system tcpdf,
 * eg. /usr/share/php/tcpdf/tcpdf.php.
 */

define('TCPDF_INC', '/usr/share/php/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

Edit the path to:

```
define('TCPDF_INC', '/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

Another option is to disable open_basedir, but the first one is the safest :)